# Нужно ли тире?

Tags: пунктуация

1. **Третий путь (-) односторонний!**
   /*мне почему-то напрашивается тире, но не могу найти аналогичный пример в справочниках*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В первом можно поставить тире между подлежащим и сказуемым.
Вторая фраза чисто разговорная, отделите запятой. *В том смысле, что он один такой.*

Не надо дублировать вопрос, от этого быстрее ответа не получите.

Comment: 1. Значит, если Я захочу... если прилагательное в роли сказуемого, тогда прокатит?

Comment: Прилагательное вполне может быть сказуемым, ничего такого здесь нет. Что такое "прокатит"? Здесь автор сам решает, поставить тире или нет. Я бы поставил, но зависит от контекста и от интонации. Откройте справочник, найдите параграф "Тире между подлежащим и сказуемым".

Comment: Если роль сказуемого играет прилагательное? Не найду примеров в справочниках.

Comment: 10. Тире, как правило, не ставится, если сказуемое выражено прилагательным, местоименным прилагательным, предложно-именным сочетанием. Например: У нее сердце очень доброе, но голова бедовая (Тургенев); Вишневый сад мой! (Чехов). Спина у акулы темно-синего цвета, а брюхо ослепительно белое (Гончаров).
Постановка тире в этих случаях имеет целью интонационно расчленить предложение и облегчить восприятие его содержания, например: Зрачки – кошачьи, длинные... (Шолохов); Высота возле разбросанных домиков хутора – командная... (Казакевич).

Comment: Спасибо, аргументация придала уверенности.